# Что можно улучшить в методе randomPointsInPolygon()?

Tags: c#, unity3d, инспекция-кода, случайные-числа, polygon

Есть метод которому передаёшь float step(влияет на количество точек (1 * step / 10000), чем больше тем больше точек), List drawcord(набор точек которые определяют площадь полигона)

```
   public static List<Vector3> randomPointsInPolygon(float step, List<Vector3> drawcord)
    {
        float mapoffsetx = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.mainSatting.mapoffsetx;
        float mapoffsety = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.mainSatting.mapoffsetz;
        if (drawcord[0].x != drawcord[drawcord.Count - 1].x && drawcord[0].z != drawcord[drawcord.Count - 1].z) //если линия, ограничивающая полигон не замкнута
            drawcord.Add(drawcord[0]); //добавляем замыкающую вершину

        float[] metricIn = new float[drawcord.Count * 2]; //дополнительный массив вершин, пересчитанный для проверки нахождения точки внутри полигона            
        drawcord[0] = new Vector3(drawcord[0].x - mapoffsetx, 0, drawcord[0].z - mapoffsety); //расчет 0-ой вершины в единицах Unity (метры)
        metricIn[0] = drawcord[0].x; metricIn[1] = drawcord[0].z; //запись 0-ой вершины в дополнительный массив. x-координаты под четными индексами, Z-координаты под нечетными индексами
        float minpointx = drawcord[0].x; //минимальная x-координата
        float maxpointx = drawcord[0].x; //максимальная х-координата
        float minpointz = drawcord[0].z; //минимальная y-координата
        float maxpointz = drawcord[0].z; //максимальная у-координата

        /*Цикл обработки вершин. начинается 1-ой вершины*/
        for (int i = 1; i < drawcord.Count; i++)
        {
            drawcord[i] = new Vector3(drawcord[i].x - mapoffsetx, 0, drawcord[i].z - mapoffsety); //расчет i-ой вершины в единицах Unity (метры)
            metricIn[i * 2] = drawcord[i].x; //запись i-ой вершины в дополнительный массив. x-координаты под четными индексами
            metricIn[i * 2 + 1] = drawcord[i].z; //запись i-ой вершины в дополнительный массив. z-координаты под нечетными индексами
            /*поиск максимальных и минимальных координат по x и максимальных и минимальных координат по z*/
            if (drawcord[i].x < minpointx)
                minpointx = drawcord[i].x;
            if (drawcord[i].x > maxpointx)
                maxpointx = drawcord[i].x;
            if (drawcord[i].z < minpointz)
                minpointz = drawcord[i].z;
            if (drawcord[i].z > maxpointz)
                maxpointz = drawcord[i].z;
        }

        float f = Area(drawcord); //Вызов функции для расчета площади полигона
        float density = f * (1 * step / 10000); //расчет требуемого числа деревьев в зависимости от пплощади и шага

        // System.Random random = new System.Random();
        int breakcount = 0; //счетчик количества деревьев

        List<Vector3> tempList = new List<Vector3>();

        /*Цикл прекращается, когда высажено достаточное количество деревьев*/
        do
        {
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(Convert.ToInt32(minpointx), Convert.ToInt32(maxpointx) + 1), 0, UnityEngine.Random.Range(Convert.ToInt32(minpointz), Convert.ToInt32(maxpointz) + 1));
            if (figures_Included(pos.x, pos.z, metricIn, drawcord.Count) == true)
            {
                tempList.Add(pos);
                breakcount++; //добавление дерева к счетчику
            }
        } while (breakcount <= density);

        return tempList;
    }

    static float Area(List<Vector3> drawcord)
    {
        float x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
        float p, a, b, c, s = 0;
        x1 = drawcord[0].x;
        y1 = drawcord[0].z;
        for (int i = 1; i < drawcord.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            x2 = drawcord[i].x;
            y2 = drawcord[i].z;
            x3 = drawcord[i + 1].x;
            y3 = drawcord[i + 1].z;
            a = (float)Math.Sqrt(((x3 - x2) * (x3 - x2)) + ((y3 - y2) * (y3 - y2)));
            b = (float)Math.Sqrt(((x3 - x1) * (x3 - x1)) + ((y3 - y1) * (y3 - y1)));
            c = (float)Math.Sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)));
            p = (a + b + c) / 2;
            s += (float)Math.Sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
        }
        return s;
    }

    static bool figures_Included(float xPoint, float yPoint, float[] metricIn, int n)
    {
        float X = xPoint;
        float Y = yPoint;
        int npol = n;
        int i, j;
        bool res = false;
        float[] XYpol = metricIn;
        for (i = 0, j = npol - 1; i < npol; j = i++)
        {
            if ((((XYpol[i * 2 + 1] <= Y) && (Y < XYpol[j * 2 + 1])) ||
                ((XYpol[j * 2 + 1] <= Y) && (Y < XYpol[i * 2 + 1]))) &&
                (X < (XYpol[j * 2] - XYpol[i * 2]) * (Y - XYpol[i * 2 + 1]) /
                    (XYpol[j * 2 + 1] - XYpol[i * 2 + 1]) + XYpol[i * 2]))
            {
                res = !res;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Что можно улучшить в коде?

Смещение. Можно задать любое, которое будет выставлять ваши точки на terrain

```
float mapoffsetx = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.mainSatting.mapoffsetx;
float mapoffsety = marijnz.EditorCoroutines.PlacementObjects.mainSatting.mapoffsetz;
```

Comment: Код рабочий? Возможно вам нужна [метка инспекция кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info)?

Comment: @AK Да код рабочий . Поставил метку

Comment: это Вы так случайным образом деревья в лесу сажаете?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Да и они очень медленно сажаются. Но на самом деле не только деревья сажаю. Ещё крашу и другие площадные объекты высаживаю

Comment: А что Вы делаете когда точки попали сильно близко друг к другу?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Все равно сажаю. Нет проверки на радиус около объекта. Тоже минус этого кода

Comment: http://www.researcharcade.com/blog/games-development/procedural-generation-techniques-poisson-disc-sampling/

Comment: ещё один метод можно добавить, если попала в радиус около другой точки

Comment: http://gregschlom.com/devlog/2014/06/29/Poisson-disc-sampling-Unity.html

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104637/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-stranger-in-the-q).