# Методы заполнения (покраски) площадных объектов (Алгоритм заполнения полигона)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, unity3d, текстура, polygon

Поделитесь своими методами либо алгоритмами покраски площадных объектов, буду очень благодарен.

По сути в задаче есть набор точек `List<Vector2>` или `List<Vector3>`, есть текстуры с разными настройками у меня они(настройки) следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И мне надо заполнить область.

У меня есть уже два алгоритма:

1. Например, которым поделились уже. Poisson-Disc
   называется, реализация на [javascript](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/dbb02448b0f93e4c82c3) , реализация на [C#](http://theinstructionlimit.com/fast-uniform-poisson-disk-sampling-in-c).(переделан под Unity [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63051178/4773571))
2. [Второй способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1084599/178835) не очень корректно работает и красит площади
   разного размера по разному.(В ссылке описано как генерируются точки
   для на несения потом на террейн текстур).

В голову приходит, например ещё такой способ заполнения площадного объекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например есть идеи как его реализовать, когда исчуться параллельные точки границы полигона , с отступом N и потом краситься по этим точкам?

Нашёл ещё [Boundary Fill Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boundary-fill-algorithm/).

Comment: Проблема неясна. Взять полигон да закрасить - чем не подходит?

Comment: @MBo Просто любые методы , которые придут на ум , для покраски полигона. Сейчас минут 10 спустя , дополню вопрос и распишу ещё, что требуется

Comment: `Graphics.FillPolygon`

Comment: Всё зависит от ваших потребностей: юзать видеокарту - WPF (DirectX), юзать процессор - WinForms (GDI), юзать своё - свой фрэймворк.

Comment: MBo использовал GDI (`System.Drawing.Graphics`, `System.Drawing.dll`).

Comment: @return у меня движок Unity. Там только есть кисти.. алгоритмов покраски террайнов я не находил уже реализованных... надо будет поискать может есть уже асеты готовые

Comment: @return реализованных в самом движке

Comment: @IvanTriumphov в Unity я не силён, помочь не могу. добавьте в метки [tag:unity] и опционально в вопросе напишите, что хотите реализацию на Unity.

Comment: @return мне не принципиально на каком языке даже предложат готовый алгоритм, главное что он заполнял полигон ... а переведу его на C# даже c  delphi или javascript ... у меня опыт огромный реанимировать код и переносить его с разных языков , даже мёртвых

Comment: раз 20 человек не смогли написать оптимальное решение, значит этот вопрос достаточно стоящий) (этот комментарий будет удалён)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110929/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-return).